# how to show message details using JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

In my messaging app my goal is to show timestamps when the message was delivered and read. In case of group messages for that a lot of space would be needed and it would not fit into cellBottomLabel. My idea is to display more details about a message after a long press on the message. How could that be done using JSQMessagesViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You need custom `JSQMessages` `NSObject` class where you can store your own data or modify existing **JSQMessages** objects.
After that try using this:

```
JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.registerMenuAction(Selector(("ShowDetails:")))
UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [UIMenuItem.init(title: "ShowDetails", action: Selector(("showDetails:")))]
```